# Prestashop Url change

Tags: ftp, prestashop

I have a problem,
I changed the url of my prestashop because I have a new url.

But now i have the Problem that i tipped in the wrong path, and if i want to log in as admin then the shop directs me everytime to the wrong path so I can't change anything...

Does anybody know in which folder of the FTP Server I can change it in the data?

I tired to delete the htaccess data but this didn't help me.

Or is it another option to go back to where I started, before i changed the Url?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem occurred not from a .htaccess but from your database. Prestashop keeps domain URL in the DB and if you changed it you better to check table `configuration` fields `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN, PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` and table `shop_url`. I think that the problem is over there.

Comment: Didn't know about the `ps_configuration` fields, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to migrate to another server, you have to

- Update the `_DB_...` constants in *config/settings.inc.php* file
  Since your database does not changed, this step is not necessary.
- Update `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` fields in `configuration` database table
- Update the `domain`, `domain_ssl` and `physical_uri` fields in the `shop_url` database table

Now you can log in to the admin page. When you did it, your first step has to go to *Preference -> SEO & URLs*, then turn off and on again the *Friendly URLs* switch to update the .htaccess files.

These steps are works on Prestashop 1.6, but not tested on 1.7.

See the official blog post for additional details:
https://www.prestashop.com/en/blog/how-to-migrate-prestashop-to-a-new-server